# Split function in python, to separate words in a sentence into a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, split

```
Sentence = print("Hello, i am the 14 year old creator of this program")
MySentence = (Sentence.lower())
```

The error :

> NoneType' object has no attribute 'lower'

I want it to be really basic and I just want the sentence to turn into a list of words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're assuming print returns the string it's printing, which is not true, it returns None (because the return type is void). You call print for the side-effect of writing to stdout, not to get a return value back.

```
words = "Hello, i am the 14 year old creator of this program".lower().split()
print(words)
```

creates a list of strings split by whitespace from a string converted to lowercase from the literal string, then prints the contents of the list.

Answer (score 0):

print is for printing the result in the console. You can try:

```
Sentence = "Hello, i am the 14 year old creator of this program"
MySentence = Sentence.lower()
print(MySentence)
```

Comment: Thank u so much... but I need to know how to split the sentence aswell

Answer (score 0):

split function split the string
and print is not use as value of variable
you must try

```
Sentence ="Hello,i am the 14 year old creator of this program"
MySentence = (Sentence.lower())
print(MySentence.split())
```

gives output as:
['hello,i', 'am', 'the', '14', 'year', 'old', 'creator', 'of', 'this', 'program']